# Determine if a string can be derived ambiguously in a CFG

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I know that given a specific context free grammar, to check if it is ambiguous requires checking if there exists any string that can be derived in more than 1 way. And this is undecidable.

However, I have a simpler problem. Given a specific context free grammar and a specific string, is it possible to determine if the string can be derived from the grammar ambiguously? Is there a general algorithm to do this check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use any generalized parsing algorithm, such as a [GLR (Tomita) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser), an [Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser), or even [a CYK parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm); all of those can produce a parse "forest" (i.e. a digraph of all possible parsers) in O(N<sup>3</sup>) time and space. Creating the parse forest is a bit trickier than the "parsing" (that is, recognition), but there are known algorithms which are referenced in the Wikipedia article.

Since the generalized parsing algorithms find all possible parses, you can rest assured that if exactly one parse is found for the string, then the string is not ambiguous.

I'd stay away from CYK parsing for this algorithm because it requires converting the grammar to Chomsky Normal Form, which makes recovering the original parse tree(s) more complicated.

Bison will generate a [GLR parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#GLR-Parsers), if requested, so you could just use that tool. However, be aware that it does not optimize storage of the parse forest, since it is expecting to produce only a single parse, and therefore you can end up with exponentially-sized datastructures (which then take exponential time to construct). That's usually only a problem with pathological grammars, though. Also, you will have to declare a [custom `%merge` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Generalized-LR-Parsing) on all possibly ambiguous productions; otherwise, the Bison-generated parser will fail with an "ambiguous parse" error if more than one parse is possible.